# RichTextBox to display the contents of a binary file

Tags: c#

I have a FileopenDialog in which i can select .txt,.bin,.prn,.dat files. After selecting this i want to read the content of the file and display it in a richtextbox.

This works file for all the files except binary file which is of some format as follows.

```
00000120  20 20 20 20 3d 20 30 78  30 30 30 30 30 30 33 30  |    ABCD@.......
00000130  0a 01 00 00 00 23 00 00  00 75 75 69 64 30 20 20  |....LD;
000001a0  20 20 20 20 20 3d 20 30  78 61 32 35 35 35 63 30  |     ABCDEF11111|
```

I want to display above ascii and hex values in a binary file in a richtextbox but it displays the output as something like.

ABCD@
LD;

Comment: "The Windows Forms RichTextBox control can display a plain-text, Unicode plain-text, or Rich-Text-Format (RTF) file" If it isn't RTF, the results won't be intelligible. Unless you are making a developers hex editor. Ref; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1z7hy77a(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a [composite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) format string:

```
str[i].ToString("X2") + " ";
```

The documentation on MSDN [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) has examples